# How to set main page in shared project in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

I'm so much new to xamarin and trying to build a cross platform application for iPhone, Android and Windows Phone.

I'm trying to create views in shared project so that i can share same view for all platform but i'm not getting that how to call that view in different projects.

As in portable project we have app.cs where we can set MainPage to set view for all projects, so how to set main page in shared project?

Please share the knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change existing code of MainActivity in YourApp.Droid project, whcih is executed first:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

You can initialize a class which inherits "Application" in "OnCreate" method inside native project. In above code App is defined in PCL, which can be defined in Shared project.

```
LoadApplication(new App_Shared());
```

Inside Shared project create a class as below:

```
public class App_Shared : Application
{
    public App_Shared()
    {
         //Set MainPage here.
    } 
}
```